# cannot find symbol error message

Tags: java, netbeans

While writing my program I got "cannot find symbol message" when I tried to invoke the method setTextArea() from another class. After compiling the program I am getting the following error message: 
Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: gui.setTextArea

Here is my code:

```
public class LinkExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String base = "http://uk.ask.com/web?q=";
        String keyword ="flowers";
        String tale="&search=&qsrc=0&o=312&l=dir";
        String url =base+keyword+tale;

        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
      AssistantGUI gui=new AssistantGUI();

        }
    }

    public static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
      ***//here is the problem line***
        gui.setTextArea(String.format(msg, args));

    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

And here is my second class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AssistantGUI {
JFrame frame= new JFrame("TextArea frame");
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
JTextArea text= new JTextArea("",5,20);


public AssistantGUI(){

frame.add(panel);
panel.add(text);
frame.setSize(250,200);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
public void setTextArea(String myString){
text.append(myString);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
AssistantGUI gui= new AssistantGUI();

gui.setTextArea("Hello");
}

}
```

I read many posts with a similar issue, but couldn't find a solution. Everything looks fine to me. I am creating an instance of AssistantGUI and then I am using it to call the method setTextArea(), why it does not recognise it? Any ideas? I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a correct answer of @RameshK. In Object Oriented style: do something like this (making things non-static):

```
AssistantGUI gui = new AssistantGUI();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new LinkExctractor().execute();
}

private void execute() {
    //Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
    String base = "http://uk.ask.com/web?q=";
    String keyword ="flowers";
    String tail = "&search=&qsrc=0&o=312&l=dir";
    String url = base + keyword + tail;

    print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

    print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
    for (Element link : links) {
        print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
    }
}

private void print...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `gui`, so naturally it cannot find it. Declaring a local variable in a different method doesn't count.

Answer (score 0):

In your first class, you instantiate a `gui` local variable in the main method. Once you exit the main method, that reference is lost and the method print cannot find it. A quick solution would be to make that `gui` a static member of your class (but that is not the proper way to go).

Consider reading this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) but more importantly, try to get rid of all those `static` (except on the main method which must remain static) and use `new` instead, use instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the gui object in the first class inside main method, it will act as a local variable.

whenever you are calling setTextArea from print method, the reference is not allowed there.

so try these alterations for your first class

```
public class LinkExtractor {
    public static AssistantGUI gui=new AssistantGUI(); // create the object
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        String base = "http://uk.ask.com/web?q=";
        String keyword ="flowers";
        String tale="&search=&qsrc=0&o=312&l=dir";
        String url =base+keyword+tale;

        print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));


        }
    }

    public static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
      ***//here is the problem line***
        gui.setTextArea(String.format(msg, args));

    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must declare gui as static for this to work. But I would not recommend that. static should be used with great caution and often people use it incorrectly (as it is here the case). Eventually, you need to make everything static and you will get into trouble.

Comment: yes you are right, we need to have static reference.. other wise we are not allowed to use that reference from static method like main...